# unexplainable error in Django

Tags: python, django

When I tried to run $ " python manage.py runserver localhost:8000 ", I get the exception error below.

Please Help!!! What am I doing wrong.

```
Request Method: GET
Django Version: 1.8.13
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 132
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python3.4
Python Version: 3.4.4
```

views.py

```
class CreateMsg(CreateView):
    #model = Visitor
    form_class = Msg
    template_name = "message.html"
```

forms.py

```
class Msg(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Visitor
         fields = ['name', 'contact', 'message']
```

main/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^contact/', include('msgapps.urls')),
]
```

msgapps/url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'msgapps.views',
    url(r'^msg/$', CreateMsg, name='CreateMsg'),
)
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to use CBV in urls you must add `.as_view()`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'msgapps.views',
    url(r'^msg/$', CreateMsg.as_view(), name='CreateMsg'),
)
```

Comment: Thanks Pythad. Excellent.